# Add RegExp matches into a list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a HTML data to be used in WebView that is coming from my API and I'm trying to extract the `data-path` attribute values using RegExp and append them into a list to further perform my functions.

```
RegExp reg = RegExp(r'data-path="(.*?)"', multiLine: true, caseSensitive: true);
List dataPaths = reg.allMatches(htmlData).toList();
```

Whenever I try printing the values in my List it returns me `Instance of '_RegExpMatch'`.

Anyone knows how do I get the data instead of the instance?

Comment: Instance of '_RegExpMatch'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

```
//Regex to match data of data-path
RegExp reg = RegExp(r'data-path="(.*?)"', multiLine: true, caseSensitive: true);

//Convert matches into List
List dataPaths = reg.allMatches(htmlData).map((data) => data.group(0)).toList();
```